# Почему происходит ошибка "createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail"?

Tags: java, android, массивы

Я пишу своё приложение. Оно работало безошибочно, но после добавления новых функций появились проблемы. После нажатия клавиши происходит ошибка:

> get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.

Класс подсчёта:

```
package com.example.carapp;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class Calculate {
    static int[] benzmoney= {12,8,10};
    static float[] factor = {1F, 0.5F,1F};
    static int[][] carprice ={{1,2,3,4},{7,8,9,10}};

    public static float calculateresult(int position,float fresult,int carposition) {
        float alfa;
        if (fresult == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if (fresult < 10000){
            return (0);
        } else{
            try {
                alfa = (fresult * factor[position]);
            } catch (){
                alfa = fresult * 1F;
            }
            float v = alfa / 10000 * carprice[carposition][0] + alfa / 40000 * carprice[position][1] + alfa / 80000 * carprice[position][2] + alfa / 150000 * carprice[position][3];
            return v;
        }
    }
    public static float calculatebenz(int position,float fresult,float cost){
        float a=(fresult/100)*cost*benzmoney[position];
        return a;
    }
}
```

В других частях ошибок нет, всё работает.
Основной код приложения:

```
package com.example.carapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class carapp extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.carapp);
        Spinner typeofroad = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.typeofroad);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> typeofroadAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this,R.array.typesofroad, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        typeofroadAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        typeofroad.setAdapter(typeofroadAdapter);
        Spinner car = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cars);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> carAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.cars, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        carAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        car.setAdapter(carAdapter);
        final EditText probegavto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.probeg);
        final EditText resultmoney = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.resultnumber);
        final EditText resultbenz = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.benz);
        final EditText benzcost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.costofbenz);
        TextView itog = findViewById(R.id.inogogogog);

        probegavto.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                recalc();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
            public void recalc(){
                float fresult;
                try {
                    fresult = Float.parseFloat(probegavto.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    fresult=0;
                }
                int position = typeofroad.getSelectedItemPosition();
                int carposition = car.getSelectedItemPosition();
                float fotvet = Calculate.calculateresult(position,fresult,carposition);
                float cost;
                try {
                    cost = Float.parseFloat(benzcost.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    cost = 0;
                }
                float fotvet1 = Calculate.calculatebenz(position,fresult,cost);
                if (fresult==0 || fresult>9999){
                    itog.setText(" ");
                } else{
                    itog.setText("Хватит на "+(int)(Math.floor(10000/fresult))+" раз(а)");
                }
                resultmoney.setText(NumberFormat.getInstance().format(fotvet)+" ₽");
                resultbenz.setText(NumberFormat.getInstance().format(fotvet1)+" ₽");
            }
            });
        typeofroad.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                recalc();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }

            public void recalc(){
                float fresult;
                try {
                    fresult = Float.parseFloat(probegavto.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    fresult=0;
                }
                int position = typeofroad.getSelectedItemPosition();
                int carposition = car.getSelectedItemPosition();
                float fotvet = Calculate.calculateresult(position,fresult,carposition);
                float cost;
                try {
                    cost = Float.parseFloat(benzcost.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    cost = 0;
                }
                float fotvet1 = Calculate.calculatebenz(position,fresult,cost);
                if (fresult==0 || fresult>9999){
                    itog.setText(" ");
                } else{
                    itog.setText("Хватит на "+(int)(Math.floor(10000/fresult))+" раз(а)");
                }
                resultmoney.setText(NumberFormat.getInstance().format(fotvet)+" ₽");
                resultbenz.setText(NumberFormat.getInstance().format(fotvet1)+" ₽");
            }
        });
        car.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                recalc();
            }

            private void recalc(){
                float fresult;
                try {
                    fresult = Float.parseFloat(probegavto.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    fresult=0;
                }
                int position = typeofroad.getSelectedItemPosition();
                int carposition = car.getSelectedItemPosition();
                float fotvet = Calculate.calculateresult(position,fresult,carposition);
                float cost;
                try {
                    cost = Float.parseFloat(benzcost.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    cost = 0;
                }
                float fotvet1 = Calculate.calculatebenz(position,fresult,cost);
                if (fresult==0 || fresult>9999){
                    itog.setText(" ");
                } else{
                    itog.setText("Хватит на "+(int)(Math.floor(10000/fresult))+" раз(а)");
                }
                resultmoney.setText(NumberFormat.getInstance().format(fotvet)+" ₽");
                resultbenz.setText(NumberFormat.getInstance().format(fotvet1)+" ₽");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
        benzcost.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                recalc();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
            public void recalc(){
                float fresult;
                try {
                    fresult = Float.parseFloat(probegavto.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    fresult=0;
                }
                int position = typeofroad.getSelectedItemPosition();
                int carposition = car.getSelectedItemPosition();
                float fotvet = Calculate.calculateresult(position,fresult,carposition);
                float cost;
                try {
                    cost = Float.parseFloat(benzcost.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    cost = 0;
                }
                float fotvet1 = Calculate.calculatebenz(position,fresult,cost);
                if (fresult==0 || fresult>9999){
                    itog.setText(" ");
                } else{
                    itog.setText("Хватит на "+(int)(Math.floor(10000/fresult))+" раз(а)");
                }
                resultmoney.setText(NumberFormat.getInstance().format(fotvet)+" ₽");
                resultbenz.setText(NumberFormat.getInstance().format(fotvet1)+" ₽");
            }
        });
        }
    }
```

Приложение считало на статических данных. Я создал массив, `carprice`, из него оно будет брать значения, подставлять, и вроде бы всё работает. Но если переключить на другой тип дороги, изменится число на которое будет домножение (массив `factor`), на маленьких числах всё работает идеально, но если числа больше `10000`, то приложение вылетает на главный экран, выдавая ошибку:

```
E/.example.carap: [qarth_debug:]  get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.carapp, PID: 22346
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
        at com.example.carapp.Calculate.calculateresult(Calculate.java:18)
        at com.example.carapp.carapp$2.recalc(carapp.java:97)
        at com.example.carapp.carapp$2.onItemSelected(carapp.java:80)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:947)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:936)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:56)
        at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:901)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Comment: Если не сможете помочь, хотя бы объясните что означает ошибка.

Comment: Весь лог ошибки покажите - там должна быть указана причина падения

Comment: E/.example.carap: [qarth_debug:]  get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.carapp, PID: 22346
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
        at com.example.carapp.Calculate.calculateresult(Calculate.java:18)
        at com.example.carapp.carapp$2.recalc(carapp.java:97)
        at com.example.carapp.carapp$2.onItemSelected(carapp.java:80)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:947)
`

Comment: at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:936)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:56)
        at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:901)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)

Comment: Вопрос надо отредактировать, и в нем написать сообщение об ошибке

Comment: У вас в массиве `carprice` только 2 строки, а судя по логу ошибки вы обращаетесь к третьей строке, и возникает выход за пределы массива.  Остальные массивы (`benzmoney`, `factor`) имеют по три элемента.

Comment: В спиннере `car` выбран третий элемент (в переменную `carposition`), но массив `carprice` рассчитан только на 2. И лишние коментарии (под вопросом) неплохо бы подчистить

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2 , проверьте сколько элементов в вашем массиве при вызове и что возвращает car.getSelectedItemPosition(). Очевидно значение > 2